# directive change on data is not reflecting on my page controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a directive which does http request , returns data and changes the value of the parameter ,

the issue is that the data returned in the directive controller reflects on HTML but does not reflect on the page controller ! 
I tried adding scope.apply() but i am having the error of digest cycle already running ..

Can you advice

**JS**

```
 app.directive('customDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
            scope : {
                pObject       :  "=",
                url           :  "@"
            } ,
        replace     : true,                
        controller  : ['$scope','$element', '$http', function($scope, $element, $http) { 

            function requestData() {
                urlParams = [];
                urlParams['x']  =  parseInt($scope.pageObj.x);
                urlParams['y']  =  parseInt($scope.pageObj.y);

                $http.get($scope.url,{ params : urlParams})
                    .success(function (data) {
                        if ( typeof data.data !=='undefined' && data.data.length > 0) {
                            $scope.pObject.data = data.data;
                            $scope.pObject.x   = data.y;
                            $scope.pObject.y   = data.y;
                        }
                    });
            }

            if (typeof $scope.pObject.data !== 'undefined' && $scope.pObject.data.length==0) {
                requestData();
            }             
}
});
```

Comment: When you declare `scope:{...}` in `directive`, the `$scope` in controller will become a **isolate scope**. So your page controller can't reach the variable in  **isolate scope**. I prefer that inject `$attr` in your directive controller then get variable  `pObject` and `url` from `$attr`.

Comment: @StevenWeng "=" means binding :) i.e. my variable must be updated in controller .. i am not talking about directive basics ,,, i want an isolated scope and i want to add parameters as local scope properties ..

Answer (score -1):

Dose your directive has pObject attribute and this attribute point to the property on page controller scope. Example:

```
<custom-directive p-object="controller Property Here"></custom-directive>
```

Please focus on how I added the pObject attribute on the directive. For more information about why i wrote it like this. Please read **Normalization** section and **Isolating the Scope of a Directive** on angular documentation.[Creating Custom Directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

Comment: this is NOT as answer the answer can not be based on assumption that I am calling my directive wrongly ... if u suspect that u can just ask me to add the code ...anyway i'm calling it with normalization and fully aware of the fact that it is isolated scope.. I am adding local scope properties and i want my object to be two ways binding

Comment: I'm sorry about that. So could you please modify your question with the full code, or create plunker and provide us with the link?